# Can only send a certain amount of SMS messages

Tags: java, android

I have a program that sends a mass text at a push of a button. It worked fine on my Evo but I just got an Evo LTE and now it is only sending to the first thirteen people out of 28.

The way it works is that it reads a list of the phone numbers from a string-array and then sends a pre-defined message based on the button I push.

I pulled a log cat and this is what I'm getting:

```
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308): null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308): java.lang.RuntimeException: null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:200)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Looper.quit(Looper.java:245)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.HandlerThread.quit(HandlerThread.java:96)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.htc.usage.service.UsageStatsService.onDestroy(UsageStatsService.java:197)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2762)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 11:25:35.320: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): @@ iconIndex=1
06-06 11:25:35.320: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): isCdma():true hasService:true mSimState=UNKNOWN gprsState=0 mDataState=2 dataActivity=4 mPhone.htcModemLinkOn:false hspa==true
06-06 11:25:35.330: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): hasService()=true ,mDataState=2 ,mPhone.htcModemLinkOn()=false ,mDataActivity=4
06-06 11:25:35.340: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): slotType[0]=SIM
06-06 11:25:35.451: V/UsageStatsService(28308): CMD_ID_UPDATE_MESSAGE_USAGE
06-06 11:25:35.471: V/UsageStatsService(28308): MSG_ON_MESSAGE_UPDATE
06-06 11:25:35.501: V/UsageStatsService(28308): MSG_STOP_SERVICE
06-06 11:25:35.501: V/UsageStatsService(28308): onDestroy
```

Never been good at reading log cats. This repeats after the thirteenth person for each remaining person. Can someone tell me what is going on?

Here is my coding: http://pastebin.com/xe4U4GYZ

Comment: Please upload the code as well

Comment: Added as a pastebin. I have 3 screens (in city, mutual aid, and custom message) set up this way since I am new to java and Android coding and haven't figured out how to get the broadcast receiver in its own file yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to the log cat, your thread has terminated already. One fix may be to make your application multi-threaded. However, look at the termination conditions for your thread and see if something is causing to die early.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I don't see how it would get terminated early. I uploaded my coding if you could take a look at it.